# Create SQL Table in PHP with variables and text

Tags: php, mysql, database, variables, database-table

I'm trying to create a SQL table in PHP using the following code:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE `$DBName`.`$login`_clients  (
  ClientID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ClientID`),
  AgentClients varchar(15),
  ClientTotal int
)";
```

The botton script runs fine and saves the database as my `$login` query. I wanted to save the table as `$login_clients` however. Ex. `$login="Fred"`, then the table would be named Fred_clients. I have tried a few different methods of combining variables with text but can't get the format down. Any suggestions?

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE `$DBName`.`$login`_clients  (
  ClientID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ClientID`),
  AgentClients varchar(15),
  ClientTotal int
)";
```

Comment: Don't you think it's bad practice to separate data in such manner?

Comment: @jperovic Clearly not. How about explaining to the OP why it might be a bad practice?

Comment: It might be just paranoia inside me but I would never grant a `CREATE` to the front-end without pretty god reason. Instead I would look up table portioning if data separation is indeed needed...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have your back tick in the wrong place, it should go after `_clients`. The problem you likely ran into was that the PHP interpreter then thought your variable was called `$login_clients` instead of `$login`, which can be solved by wrapping the variable in curly braces `{}`.

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE `{$DBName}`.`{$login}_clients`  (
  ClientID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ClientID`),
  AgentClients varchar(15),
  ClientTotal int
)";
```

Comment: You'll want to be super mega careful that `$login` does not contain anything harmful here.

Comment: Also note the proper use of encapsulation in the answer. Encapsulation is very important.

Comment: @doublesharp thanks for your help, this clears up my questions on braces! Once I can choose an answer, this will be it. :)

Comment: @BlaineHurtado no problem - take note of what @tadman posted as well, you want to make sure that your `$login` variable is what you expect it to be, if you are accepting input from a form for example this could be used for a SQL injection attack.

Comment: @doublesharp This page requires a valid session cookie through a previous login. Other than sanitizing values and checking for input validations/existing logins, would you recommend other extra securities? Once again, everyone's help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE `$DBName`.`" . $login . "_clients`  (
  ClientID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ClientID`),
  AgentClients varchar(15),
  ClientTotal int
)";
```